# How does an NAS stream videos to a TV?

Tags: video, nas, video-streaming

I have a WD EX2100 and got a Samsung TV UN55JS8500. Surprisingly, when pressing Source, the TV actually let me select the NAS and was able to play videos stored in the NAS.

(the TV will show my PC as well, although for some reason it shows 0 videos on that PC... but that PC definitely has some videos on it)

What technology is this -- is it DLNA or UPnP?  I think the video appeared less smooth than if I play the videos on an iMac, or if I pass the video output to the TV using HDMI.  I wonder if the video is transcoded when played, and what types of video formats (mp4, avi) are supported?

I wonder if using a computer may still be a better choice, as it is more customizable for audio or subtitle selection, and I can also make some DVDs into a single .iso file, and play it on the computer using VLC player, and have no need to swap the discs in or out, or worry about having the disc scratched or misplaced.

Answer (score 1):

Check your TV's specifications to see what sort of streaming is supported, as well as which file formats and codecs are handled. Then log into the HTTP interface on your NAS to see which services are enabled.

The PC is showing no files is because you haven't set up any directories to share over UPnP/DLNA.

The PC has far more processing and graphics power than a TV, which, combined with a lot more memory for buffering, makes it much better able to keep up with a data stream.

On the other hand, a PC application is more vulnerable to contention from other software, so its generally smoother picture may not be maintained for the whole length of of a film.